# White Flash when using Touchswipe js on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, kik

I am currently writing a mobile web app thats uses [touchwipe js](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) library to display an image gallery. The app works as expected on iPhone, but on Android there is a very annoying white flash that appears when swiping between images.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App.js is a mobile web framework for building high quality apps. There is a dedicated photo gallery plugin that deals will all of these issues and ensures high quality.

App.js: http://code.kik.com/app/2/

Photo gallery: http://code.kik.com/app/2/docs.html#ui-photoviewer